# Diffusion between unequally spaced points?

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics

I believe what I have is a rather simple issue at heart: assume I have a number of $M$ scattered points in an $N$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^N$. Each of these points has coordinates $x \in \mathbb{R}^N $ and a specific temperature $T_0(x)$. I also know the diffusion coefficient $D$.

Further assume that I have no information between these points and my space is too high-dimensional for a grid approximation, so I want to solve the system *implicitly* only at the $M$ points. Now according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) I could solve this system at each given point if I knew the second spatial derivatives of the temperatures along each dimension:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=D\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{d^2T}{dn^2}$$

where $n$ are the spatial dimensions. I could theoretically get these derivatives from piecewise polynomials, but I would like to solve the system implicitly. Is there a way to approximate these derivatives numerically? Unfortunately, the point coordinates in each dimension are unequally spaced.

Comment: How large are you expecting $N$ to be?

Comment: Difficult to say. Let's assume 10000-dimensional

Comment: Well with that many dimensions, I believe your only choice would be Monte Carlo methods.

Comment: To be clear, though, you do actually mean 10,000 dimensions and not 10,000 spatial points along a single axis $x\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, right?

Comment: Yes, I did actually mean 10,000 dimensions. I only have $m << 10,000$ spatial points.